# Using annotations and aggregations without getting duplicates

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a `queryset` in my Django app. The queryset is accessing information across several tables filled with products information (**price per provider**, name, stock, etc... the *usual* stuff that you'd find in a shopping-related application).

Since one product can have multiple prices, I'm ending up with duplicated products. This is actually fine and logical, since SQL is just showing me as many duplicated products as prices each product has.

That's where I use aggregations:

```py
queryset.annotate(
   annotate_min_price=Min("product_prices__price"),
)
```

That makes my queryset to return only the lowest price for each product, which stops the products from getting duplicated.

At this point the query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "prod_prod"."id",
    ...
    MIN ( "monetary_prodprice"."system_all_included_price" ) AS "annotate_min_price" 
FROM
    "prod_prod"
    INNER JOIN "monetary_prodprice" ON ( "prod_prod"."id" = "monetary_prodprice"."prod_id" )
    INNER JOIN "monetary_pricelist" ON ( "monetary_prodprice"."pricelist_id" = "monetary_pricelist"."id" )
    INNER JOIN "monetary_pricelistdestinations" ON ( "monetary_pricelist"."id" = "monetary_pricelistdestinations"."pricelist_id" )
    INNER JOIN "prodtransaction_carrier_pricelists" ON ( "monetary_pricelist"."id" = "prodtransaction_carrier_pricelists"."pricelist_id" )
    INNER JOIN "prodtransaction_carrier" ON ( "prodtransaction_carrier_pricelists"."carrier_id" = "prodtransaction_carrier"."id" )
    INNER JOIN "prodtransaction_carrierdelivery" ON ( "prodtransaction_carrier"."id" = "prodtransaction_carrierdelivery"."carrier_id" )
    INNER JOIN "monetary_pricelistcountry" ON ( "monetary_pricelist"."id" = "monetary_pricelistcountry"."pricelist_id" ) 
WHERE
    (
        ...
    ) 
GROUP BY
    "prod_prod"."id",
ORDER BY
    "annotate_min_price" DESC
```

The problem is that, besides the lowest price, I need to get the actual `ID` of that price. So I modify my queryset accordingly:

```py
queryset.annotate(
    annotate_min_price=Min("prod_prices__system_all_included_price"),
    annotate_best_price=F('prod_prices__pk')).order_by(ordering)
```

This is where I'm hitting the problem. This will produce the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "prod_prod"."id",
    ...
    MIN ( "monetary_prodprice"."system_all_included_price" ) AS "annotate_min_price",
    "monetary_prodprice"."id" ) AS "annotate_best_price" 
FROM
    "prod_prod"
    INNER JOIN "monetary_prodprice" ON ( "prod_prod"."id" = "monetary_prodprice"."prod_id" )
    INNER JOIN "monetary_pricelist" ON ( "monetary_prodprice"."pricelist_id" = "monetary_pricelist"."id" )
    INNER JOIN "monetary_pricelistdestinations" ON ( "monetary_pricelist"."id" = "monetary_pricelistdestinations"."pricelist_id" )
    INNER JOIN "prodtransaction_carrier_pricelists" ON ( "monetary_pricelist"."id" = "prodtransaction_carrier_pricelists"."pricelist_id" )
    INNER JOIN "prodtransaction_carrier" ON ( "prodtransaction_carrier_pricelists"."carrier_id" = "prodtransaction_carrier"."id" )
    INNER JOIN "prodtransaction_carrierdelivery" ON ( "prodtransaction_carrier"."id" = "prodtransaction_carrierdelivery"."carrier_id" )
    INNER JOIN "monetary_pricelistcountry" ON ( "monetary_pricelist"."id" = "monetary_pricelistcountry"."pricelist_id" ) 
WHERE
    (
        ...
    ) 
GROUP BY
    "prod_prod"."id",
    "monetary_prodprice"."id"
ORDER BY
    "annotate_min_price" DESC
```

This makes my queryset duplicate the products. I understand that this is happening because I'm asking PostgreSQL to add the `ID` of the prices to each row (product), and that somehow breaks the `MIN` aggregator.

My question is: how can I make Django return only the products with the lowest price **and**  the ID of that price at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

you can use subqueries

```
min_query =
    ProductPrice.objects.filter(product_id=OuterRef('id'))
    .order_by('system_all_included_price')
    .values('system_all_included_price', 'id')[:1]

queryset.annotate(
    annotate_min_price=Subquery(
        min_query.values('system_all_included_price')
    ).annotate(
    annotate_min_id=Subquery(
        min_query.values('id')
    )
).order_by(ordering)
```

**Solution below does not work as pointed out in the comments because you cannot reference a window function in the filter**

You should be able to annotate each product with the min price

```
queryset.annotate(
    annotate_min_price=Window(
        expression=Min("prod_prices__system_all_included_price"),
        partition_by=F('prod_prices__pk'),
        order_by=ordering,
    ),
).filter(annotate_min_price=F('prod_prices__system_all_included_price)
```

if you can have equal prices in some cases then you might want to go again through a annotate partition by to identify the lowest id this time and then filter on the ID matching the lowest.

```
queryset.annotate(
    annotate_min_id=Window(
        expression=Min("prod_prices__pk"),
        partition_by=F('prod_prices__system_all_included_price'),
        order_by=ordering,
    ),
).filter(annotate_min_id=F('prod_prices__pk'))
```

Comment: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.

Comment: I tried this, but apparently `Window is disallowed in the filter clause`.

Comment: I believe it is only supported on specific dbs, postgres for sure. There should be also a way to do this without partition by using subquery, later if I have time I can give you an example.

Comment: Done of the top of my head as I can't test it right now.

Comment: From django doc:

`filterable: Defaults to False. The SQL standard disallows referencing window functions in the WHERE clause and Django raises an exception when constructing a QuerySet that would do that.`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.Window.filterable

Comment: I am stupid. Of course the problem is the filter referencing the min. So not a viable option. Then subquery it is ...

Comment: Your last update is doing what my `Min` (from my first code example) is doing. You're missing the second annotate. That's the difficult part.

Comment: Corrected to include id of the price